# Enum associated values

Tags: swift, enums

I'm trying to understand Swift's Enum. I want to assign my enum case an associated value and have a computed value returned. Currently I'm using a method for returning the calculated number.

```
enum Calculation {
    case Number1(number: Int)
    case Number2(number: Int)

    func calculation() -> Int {
        switch self {
        case Number1(let number): return number + 1
        case Number2(let number): return number + 2
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering if it could be done shorter like:

```
// This obviously doesn't work. Just an example as what I'm trying to achieve
enum Calculation: Int {
    case Number1(number: Int): return number + 1
    case Number2(number: Int): return number + 2
}
```

Comment: This answer may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32530320/3222419

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Enums that use closures?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450971/swift-enums-that-use-closures)

Comment: `"I was wondering if it could be done shorter like: example"`  Did you even bother trying and finding out that your example doesn't work?  Did you put any research effort in whatsoever?  Your syntax doesn't even really make sense to me...

Comment: @DavidWilliames I can't see what the linked answer has anything to do with this really.  There's nothing about closures here... did you just link the first enum associated type question you found?

Comment: @nhgrif- No I did not simply link the first enum related question I could find!! It appears that what he is trying to do is store a 'calculation' as an enum that essentially performs a calculation on a number and returns it's result.... that is essentially wanting to store closures in his enum.

Comment: I'm still looking at the suggested answer, but it doesn't seem it's what I want though. @nhgrif Yes I have. With that last example, I'm very well aware that it doesn't work. I was only hoping to make it easier and clear to the readers as what I want as a result.

Comment: @DavidWilliames That moves control over the actual calculation from *inside* this type to *outside* this type, and even still, it requires actually performing the calculation... and that block of code probably isn't *really* that much simpler than his current `calculation()` method implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The question is whether you want to use a computed variable:

```
enum Calculation {
    case Number1(number: Int)
    case Number2(number: Int)

    var value:Int {
        switch self {
        case Number1(let number): return number + 1
        case Number2(let number): return number + 2
        }
    }

}
```

Or have the value stored as the associated value:

```
enum CalculationType {
    case Number1, Number2
}
enum Calculation {

    case Number1(number: Int)
    case Number2(number: Int)

    init (type:CalculationType, number:Int) {
        switch type {
        case .Number1:
            self = Calculation.Number1(number: number + 1)
        case .Number2:
            self = Calculation.Number2(number: number + 2)
        }

    }
}
```

Your question points towards the former but I'm not clear from your second piece of code whether you were expecting the latter or hoping that initialization would return a value, which can't happen (an `init` does not return a value). The closest thing would be to have a static function:

```
enum CalculationType {
    case Number1, Number2
}
enum Calculation {
    case Number1(number: Int)
    case Number2(number: Int)

    static func calc(type:CalculationType, number:Int) -> (Calculation, Int) {
        switch type {
        case .Number1:
            return (Calculation.Number1(number: number), number + 1)
        case .Number2:
            return  (Calculation.Number2(number: number), number + 2)
        }
    }

}

Calculation.calc(.Number1, number: 2)
```

Alternatively you could use a callback on the `init`:

```
enum CalculationType {
    case Number1, Number2
}
enum Calculation {

    case Number1(number: Int)
    case Number2(number: Int)

    init (type:CalculationType, number:Int, callback:(Int) -> Void) {
        switch type {
        case .Number1:
            self = Calculation.Number1(number: number)
            callback(number + 1)
        case .Number2:
            self = Calculation.Number2(number: number)
            callback(number + 2)
        }

    }

}


Calculation(type: .Number1, number: 10, callback: {n in print(n)})
```